# Why is my output messed up for printing out 2-d array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

public class chessboardUsingArray {

```
private Car[][] myBoard = new Car[8][8];

public chessboardUsingArray() {

    // make sure at the end of this constructor, myBoard is 8x8 and each car
    // in it is set to NULL

    for (int x = 0; x < myBoard.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < myBoard[x].length; y++) {

            myBoard[x][y] = null;
            // System.out.print(myBoard[x][y] + " ");

        }

        // System.out.println();

    }
}

public void printBoard() {

    for (int x = 0; x < myBoard.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < myBoard[x].length; y++) {

            Car defaultCar = myBoard[x][y];
            if (defaultCar != null) {
                System.out.println("   " + defaultCar.getMake() + " ");
            } else {

                System.out.print("   X   ");
            }

        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}


public boolean placeCar(int y, int x, Car myCar) {

    if (x >= 0 && x < 8 && y >= 0 && y < 8) {

        if (myBoard[x][y] == null) {

            myBoard[x][y] = myCar;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The place car function should place a car in the specified coordinates and return everything else with an `X` as specified. When I try to put a car in location (2, 3) this happens... The car is placed correctly as you can see with an `H` but do some of the other locations disappear?

X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      H
   X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
   X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X

the five X 's to the right of H disappear as do three others below it. idk why its not being shown correctly. any ideas? thanks

Comment: Looks like you're never calling `placeCar`...

Answer (score 2):

You are using println for car make which results in X's after that to be shown on the next line